# PHP XSLTProcessor Compilation error

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Cannot make transformation with stylesheet, which has entity inside xsl:text node. I've got no errors and empty output if I put &some; outside xsl:text node.

**test.php**

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('test.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('test.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<test>123</test>
```

**test.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY some "22323"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>&some;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Got error:

```
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsltParseTemplateContent: xslt:text content problem in /Users/stexe/Repos/umi.cms.2/test.php on line 13

Call Stack:
    0.0003     226288   1. {main}() /Users/stexe/Repos/umi.cms.2/test.php:0
    0.0009     228424   2. XSLTProcessor->importStylesheet() /Users/stexe/Repos/umi.cms.2/test.php:13
```

Os X, PHP 5.4.45 (Homebrew)

**PHP info**:

```
libxml2 Version => 2.9.5
ibxslt Version => 1.1.29
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.9.4
```

Comment: PHP and XSLT tagged in same question? Be still my heart...Anyways, the ampersand, `&`, is a special XML entity and its symbol cannot standalone. And do note XML entities are not the same as HTML entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting

```
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->substituteEntities = TRUE;
```

before the `load` call.